# Invariant violations get grouped in Stackdriver error reporting

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

I am using the npm module "invariant" a lot in my code to do runtime checks and throw errors. The problem is that Stackdriver error reporting seems to group all of these errors together because they originate from the same function and/or start with the phrase "Invariant violation...".

Is there a way I can prevent this grouping from happening without refactoring all of the code?

It is a big problem for me because some critical errors do not surface and are not reported as new, so it kind of defeats a big part of why I have error reporting in the first place.

----- some samples ----

```
{ Invariant Violation: You are not allowed to report the same data as the previous report
    at invariant (/srv/node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/src/modules/loads/respond.ts:123:5)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/srv/build/modules/loads/respond.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7) name: 'Invariant Violation', framesToPop: 1 }

{ Invariant Violation: User uoipWa1yARgdudN4mFmtYrYoOID3 is not subscribed to flight 2f0291571b06322e2737b627fdca2ff0
    at invariant (/srv/node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/src/modules/loads/request.ts:373:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/srv/build/modules/loads/request.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7) name: 'Invariant Violation', framesToPop: 1 }
```

Comment: Could you give a couple samples of what the resulting stack / exception looks like?

Comment: I've added some samples

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion is to fix the invariant violations and then mark the error group as "[Resolved](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/managing-errors#resolution-status)".  Any additional invariant errors will be treated as though there were new.

Comment: I can't just fix all violations. Some are triggered by user behavior, and in order to prevent them the client needs to change its UX / client-side validation. Also some are a result of complex dependencies and system failures that are occur occasionally.

But grouping also happens for other errors that are not invariant violations. I have yet to discover a pattern behind it, but it's a big mess.